# Nested reactive forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to dynamically create a nested FormArray in my Angular 6 application.

I have a quote, which has a collection of quote-items

```
export class Quote {
    quoteId: number;
    quoteItems: QuoteItem[]
    status: string;
}

export class QuoteItem {

    quoteItemId: number;
    description: string;
    quoteItemDetails: QuoteItemDetail[]
}

export class QuoteItemDetail {        
    quoteItemDetailId: number;
    rate: number;
    quantity: number;
    total: number;
}
```

I have a form that has the Quote object, where a user can click on a button to add and remove one or more QuoteItems.

This is my code where I initialise my form:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.quoteForm = this.fb.group({
        status: [''],
        quoteItems: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.addQuoteItem();
}
```

And this is how I get the dynamic adding and removing working:

```
get quoteItems() {
    return this.quoteForm.get('quoteItems') as FormArray;
}  

addQuoteItem() {
    this.quoteItems.push(this.fb.group({
        description: '',
        quoteItemDetails: this.fb.array([])
    }));
}


removeQuoteV2Item(index) {
  this.quoteV2Items.removeAt(index);
}
```

And my html:

```
<div formArrayName="quoteItems">

    <div @items *ngFor="let item of quoteItems.controls; let contentIndex=index" [formGroupName]="contentIndex">
        <input type="text" formControlName="description">
    </div>
</div>

<p>
  <a (click)="addQuoteItem()">Add Quote Item</a>
</p>
```

What I'm trying to do is then have the same functionality but for my QuoteItemDetail array.  So a user can add one or more quoteItems, and within them add one or more QuoteItemDetails.

I'm really stuck at the first point, I can't work out how to get a form array assessor, this doesn't work as an example, as I'm not sure how to pass the index across:

```
get quoteItemDetails() {
  return this.quoteItems.get('quoteItemDetails') as FormArray;
}
```

Comment: check David's response. Well, he forgot a formArrayName, but the idea is good:not use a getter, use a normal function that you pass the index as argument. If you want see your example, I hope this statblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyslvo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do it with an accessor. The accessor is going to give you a reference to one attribute. But as you said, in this case you need an index to specify what quoteItemDetails FormArray reference you need (since as far as I understand you want a FormArray in each quoteItem, so each quoteItem can have several quoteItemDetails, right?).

I don't see a problem with that though. Instead of doing it with an accessor like you have done with the quoteItems, you will have to do it with a method taking the one parameter you need, the index. Something like this:

```
quoteItemDetails(quoteItemIndex: number): FormArray {
  return this.quoteItems.at(quoteItemIndex).get('quoteItemDetails') as FormArray;
}
```

And then you represent it on the template:

```
<div formArrayName="quoteItems">

  <div @items *ngFor="let item of quoteItems.controls; let contentIndex=index" [formGroupName]="contentIndex">
    <input type="text" formControlName="description">
    <div *ngFor="let quoteItemDetail of quoteItemDetails(contentIndex).controls; let detailIndex=index" [formArrayName]="detailIndex">
      <input type="number" formControlName="description" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you. I have not tested the code but the solution should be someshere along these lines.

Comment: Thank you, was able to solve this with yours and @Eliseo's help